# C++ Heap Object has Stack or Heap Members?

Tags: c++, class, heap-memory, member

If I allocate a new object on the heap, are all variables defined within the class of the object also on the heap?

For example, say I have a Node class that has an x, y, z coordinate held within an array called _pos. For the sake of the user creating many Node objects, Node is declared on the heap as:

```
Node n = new Node(0, 0, 0);
```

Should I also declare the position array on the heap as:

```
class Node {
public:
  Node(double x, double y, double z) {
    _pos = new double[3] {x, y, z};
  }

private:
  double* _pos;
}
```

Or is the _pos array already considered on the heap and the following works as well

```
class Node {
public:
  Node(double x, double y, double z) {
    _pos = double[3] {x, y, z};
  }

private:
  double* _pos;
}
```

I'm guessing the second one is also considered on the heap, in which case it also makes deallocation a bit easier, but I'm hoping someone can confirm.

Comment: "Should I also declare the position array on the heap" No it's not necessary. (Why would it be?)

Comment: Both alternatives do completely different things. there is no "right" or "wrong" here, it depends. Only you know what the correct answer is, because only you know how the rest of application uses these objects. To determine the correct answer you will need to review the explanation your C++ book gives you about objects, automatic scope, and dynamic scope.

Answer (score 0):

> If I allocate a new object on the heap, are all variables defined within the class of the object also on the heap?

Yes.